# Google Sheets - get date of max value

Tags: google-sheets, maxifs

I would like to populate a cell which gives me the date where sales was the highest for that period.  eg. if I have 2 months, I would like to have a cell saying 14/01/2023 if that was the day with the highest sales.
Q - sales values
R - Year
I can get the highest sales value for the year:

```
=MAXIFS(Pivot!Q2:Q1000, Pivot!R2:R1000, "2023")
```

but struggle to get the highest date using similar as it just brings back the max date.

I have another column P which is the date.  Anyone have any thoughts as to how to do this?  To recap I want the date of the most sales  - this year.

Thanks

Comment: `QUERY()` with `MAX()` function can work. Share few sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=filter(Pivot!P2:P,Pivot!R2:R=2023,Pivot!Q2:Q=max(Pivot!Q2:Q))
```

Comment: thanks for the reposnse - I got this error message:

Error
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 999. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1000, column count: 1.

Comment: can you try the updated one...

Comment: Thanks - I now get no matches are found in filter evaluation:

PivotDate(P) Portfolio Total(Q) Year(R)
20230101 $1,081                 2023
20230113 $1,091                 2023
20230114 $1,127                 2023

This is an example of the typical data by the way.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JIcJ1v2.png Here's how it generally works based on your sample data.